# is_home() in HTML head

Tags: homepage, conditional-tags, frontpage

Is there a way to check if the current page is the home page from within the head?

My `style.php` needs the number of posts in the slider, but only on the home page. So I count my posts like this:

```
<?php 
$meta_key = 'teaser';
$posts_per_page = 6;

$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT pm.post_id)
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm
    JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
    WHERE pm.meta_key = '$meta_key'
    AND pm.meta_value != ' '
    AND (p.post_type = 'post' OR p.post_type = 'page' OR p.post_type = 'ai1ec_event')
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'";

$count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
if($count > $posts_per_page) {
    $count = $posts_per_page;
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots/style.php?tcount=<?php echo $count;?>" />
```

I tried to wrap it in an `if` statement, but `is_home()` or `is_frontpage()` do not work.

This is the style.php (Just some relevant parts, to show how it works):

```
header("Content-Type: text/css"); 
$seconds_to_cache = 86400;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds_to_cache");

$numTeasers = $_GET['tcount'];

/* ==========================================================================
    Slider Controls
========================================================================== */

$max = $numTeasers;
for ($s = 1; $s <= $max; $s++) {

    $next = $s+1;
    if($next == $max+1){$next = 1;}
    echo "#wdgt_slider #slide".$s.":checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(".$next."){background: url('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots/assets/img/slider/next.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;display:block;position:absolute;right:0;margin:0 20px 0 0;}";

    $prev = $s-1;
    if($prev == 0){$prev = $max;}
    echo "#wdgt_slider #slide".$s.":checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(".$prev."){background: url('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots/assets/img/slider/prev.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;display:block;position:absolute;float:left;margin: 0 0 0 20px;}";

    echo "#wdgt_slider #slide".$s.":checked ~ #active label:nth-child(".$s."){color:#c2b29e}";

    echo "#wdgt_slider #slide".$s.":checked ~ #slides #slide-teaser-".$s." .info, #wdgt_slider #slide".$s.":checked ~ #slides #slide-teaser-".$s."{visibility:visible;width:100%;height:auto;opacity:1;}";
}

@import url(“../adventon/style.css”);
```

Is it bad practice to do such things in the HTML head?

Comment: Both work from inside `header.php`. Please show your code and why you have a style.php file.

Comment: If your running a database query to pass a variable to a style.php file your doing_it_wrong()

Comment: I edited my question and added the code.

Comment: And I have a style php, because my slider works just with CSS and therefore the CSS has to know how much slides there are.

Comment: There is almost assuredly a better way to do this. Can you please post the `style.php` code?

Comment: I posted style.php.

Comment: I got the if statement to work now. I dont know the reason it didnt work before. But I'm still interested, if there is a better practice for my CSS Slider. It works perfectly now and I cant see any downsides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` works in the header or anywhwere you are using a theme template.

Most likely, the problem is because you've hardcoded this: `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots/style.php`

Try instead creating your url like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/style.php?tcount=<?php echo $count;?>" />`